# How to get a response out of send_data Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, pdf-generation

The problem is the following, in our system the users  export a really big amount of data, which is filtered by many factors and mysql query takes very long to put that data into pdf/csv format.

What we want to do is disable the export button until the export process is complete and then show a download windows.

I generate pdf with `PdfGem` gem

```
pdf = PdfGen::Generate.generate_rates_header(options)
pdf = PdfGen::Generate.generate_personal_wholesale_rates_pdf(pdf, data1, data2, options)
```

`PdfGen::Generate` method constructs the pdf file, after that I use:

```
send_data(file, type: mimetype, filename: filename)
```

where `mimetype` is "application/pdf" and `filename` depends on users settings.

Anyone has any ideas how to get response when pdf generation is completed?

Comment: Add tag and Improve format and grammar

Comment: Use a background job to do the heavy lifting asynchronously ?